# Onclick is visiting the link regardless of returning false

Tags: javascript

I am trying to submit an ajax function via a link click, I am using onclick like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>watchlist/remove/<?php echo System::escape($this->item->item_id); ?>" onclick="manage_watchlist(); return false;" id="watchlist">
    Remove From Watchlist
</a>
```

and my function:

```
var manage_watchlist = function(e)
{
    alert("ff");
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.success)
            {
                if($(this).hasClass("remove"))
                {
                    $(this).text("Add to Watchlist");
                    $(this).removeClass("remove").addClass("add");
                    $(this).attr('href', '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>watchlist/add/<?php echo System::escape($this->item->item_id); ?>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).text("Remove from Watchlist");  
                    $(this).removeClass("add").addClass("remove");
                    $(this).attr('href', '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>watchlist/remove/<?php echo System::escape($this->item->item_id); ?>');
                }
                $('#watch_success_message').html(data.success + alert_close).show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#watch_error_message').html(data.error + alert_close).show();
            }
                <!-- hide loading icon -->
                $('.ajloading').hide();
        },
        error: function()
        {
            <!-- hide loading icon -->
            $('.ajloading').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I have put an alert in the function which works so my function is working, but it is still visiting the link for some reason?

Comment: You shouldn't need both `return false` and `e.preventDefault()`... I'd recommend just using the later.

Comment: `this` inside `$.ajax` call is `$.ajax` object.

Comment: Returning false won't prevent the link from firing. It will "only" stop the propagation (it is different when the listener is set with jQuery but it is not what you are doing here).

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know. I was testing both.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in event with the inline event handler.

```
onclick="manage_watchlist(event);"
```

or better yet, dump the inline event and use jQuery to attach the event.

Answer (score 0):

For an inline event `e.preventDefault();` "prevents" return false.

Use only `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>watchlist/remove/<?php 
echo System::escape($this->item->item_id); ?>" id="watchlist">
    Remove From Watchlist
</a>

//JS
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#watchlist').click(function(e){
     var $this = $(this); //**this** is the anchor
     e.preventDefault(); //e is click event.
     $.ajax({//use $this when you mean the anchor
        //**this** here is $.ajax
        //...
        //your code here
     });//$.ajax
   });//$('#watchlist').click
});//$(document).ready
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put code into the string for onclick it does not act as you may think it does. It behaves similar to this:

```
function(event) {
    manage_watchlist();
}
```

which is why you must pass the event object to your function in the html onclick.

```
onclick="manage_watchlist(event);"
```

will look like

```
function(event) {
    manage_watchlist(event);
}
```